# Writing a sub-query using a date clause

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, date-arithmetic

So basically I'm trying to write something that prints the customer's name and area code if they have made a booking within the last 6 months of the current date.

My code looks like this **(it has to be a subquery, not using join)**

```
SELECT custfirstname, custareacode
FROM Customer
WHERE customerid IN (SELECT bookingdate
                FROM Bookings
                  WHERE DateDiff(CURDATE(), bookingdate) <=180);
```

Yet it doesn't work, but I can get it to work using a join function, but I can't with subquery, how would I do it in a subquery without a join function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select `customerid` from `bookings table`

```
SELECT custfirstname, custareacode
FROM Customer
WHERE customerid IN (SELECT customerid
                FROM Bookings
                  WHERE DateDiff(CURDATE(), bookingdate) <=180);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the subquery returns column `bookingdate`, that you are then comparing to `customerid`. This won't match.

I would recommend `exists` and a correlated subquery. Assuming that you do have column `customerid` in `bookings`, then:

```
select c.custfirstname, c.custareacode
from customer c
where exists (
    select 1
    from bookings b
    where b.customerid = b.customerid 
      and b.bookingdate >= current_date - interval 6 month
)
```

With the right index in place, `exists` performs usually far better than `in()` over a large dataset. Here, you want an index on `bookings(customerid, bookingdate)`.